# boost log tutorial trivial logging example does not link on VS2010

Tags: boost-log

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << " a trace message ";
}
```

Unresolved external symbols to boost::system, filesystem3, coecvt.

Oddly the examples\basic_usage and multiple_threads link and work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
#include <boost/log/utility/init/to_file.hpp>
```

Comment: what do you mean by this. Looks like boost library should be linked with.

Comment: Adding that header fixed the boost auto link feature that was not pulling in the proper boost libraries.